# Polymorphism in c++ - Access functions over pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Got the following simple structure:

```
    class Base {
    public:
        virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
    };
    
    class Derived1 : public Base {
    public:
        void foo() override { std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl; }
        void boo() {}
    };
    
    class Derived2 : public Base {
    public:
        void foo() override { std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl; }
    };
    
    int main(){
        Base* p1 = new Derived1();
        Base* p2 = new Derived2();
    
        p1->foo();
        p1->boo();
    }
```

Now my question is: how can i access the Derived1::boo() function (with the pointer p1, so I still have the polymorphism) when i don't want it to be accessible for objects of Derived2?

Comment: You would have to cast it.

Comment: One way is to use a `dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(base)` or `static_cast<Derived1*>(base)`.

Comment: If `p1->boo()` is supposed to be invalid for a `Derived2` object, how is your code (assuming more complexity than this appropriately simplified example) supposed to know it's OK to call `p1->boo()`? A pointer to `Base`, like `p1`, is allowed to point to a `Derived2` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can be sure the pointer points to a `Derived1` object, then `static_cast` it:

```
static_cast<Derived1*>(p1)->boo();
```

If you don't know if it points to a `Derived1` object, then you need to test for that first with a `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (auto* as_derived1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(p1)) {
    as_derived1->boo();
}
```

`dynamic_cast` will evaluate to `nullptr` if the pointer you are casting does not actually point to a `Derived1`. `static_cast` does not perform this check, making it faster. But if the pointer you are casting does not actually point to a `Derived1` object, then accessing the resulting pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this code would compile?

`p1` is being accessed as a `Base*`, and `Base*` does not declare or implement `boo`.  If you believe that `p1` actually points to a `Derived1`, you can cast the pointer.

Otherwise, your class definitions would only expose `boo` as a method on `Derived1` and its inheritors.

Comment: This is regular C++ pointer casting, nothing particular to do with your question.  `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` are two options.  There are plenty of resources with more information.

Comment: Well, do what you want. IMO your answer would be better to be self contained and complete. There are 6 different types of casting supported by c++, I believe clarity would be good, which ones to use in particular. Also note: It  isn't _my question_.

Comment: If you have an improvement that you'd like to see in my answer, please feel free to submit an edit!

Comment: @ajm It is considered inappropriate to edit an answer when it goes against the author's intent. You have expressed that your intent is to provide an incomplete answer. Therefore, no one should edit your answer to make it complete (unless you change your mind about leaving the answer incomplete).

Comment: I'm sorry, I hope my intent was clear when I invited you to submit an edit.  I'm happy to edit my answer to make it more clear, but I am not necessarily willing to spend more time to do additional research beyond what I've already invested into my answer.

Comment: @ajm I see. You are not opposed to giving an example of "regular C++ pointer casting", but rather you don't know how (without conducting additional research)?

Comment: Hey, really not interested in having bad faith discussions, sorry, this discussion's over :)  You can post your own answer or edit mine, those are your options with me.